# Connecting to Redundant NFS Servers (Load Balancers or Round-Robin DNS?)

Tags: domain-name-system, load-balancing, filesystems, nfs

In a typical NFS setup with redundant servers (multiple boxes), do people use a load balancer or round-robin DNS to achieve a single connection vector for clients?

Is there a better way to do this without manually adding the IP address of each NFS share to each client machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to read on this: [Highly Available NFS Server Using DRBD And Heartbeat On Debian 5.0 (Lenny)](http://www.howtoforge.com/highly-available-nfs-server-using-drbd-and-heartbeat-on-debian-5.0-lenny)